# pyspark split string into key value pair and extract certain values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have column with multiple key value pairs as a string.

Ex:

```
rb=99;cs_y1=0;y2_co=CA;y2_r=ON;y2_ct=Kitchener;y2_z=N2N;y2_isp=Bell DSL Internet;y2_org=Bell DSL Internet
```

I need to extract the values corresponding to the keys y2_co,y2_r,y2_z and y2_org.

```
df.withColumn("co", split(split(col("_c1"), ";").getItem(2)),"=").getItem(1))
.withColumn("r",    split(split(col("_c1"), ";").getItem(3)),"=").getItem(1))
.withColumn("z",    split(split(col("_c1"), ";").getItem(5)),"=").getItem(1))
.withColumn("org",  split(split(col("_c1"), ";").getItem(7),"=").getItem(1))
```

I have the above that works for this one string but the number of key value pairs is not constant.How do I tweak the above statement to handle variable length key value pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [str_to_map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#str_to_map), see below:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

keys = ["y2_co", "y2_r", "y2_z", "y2_org"]

df.withColumn('m', F.expr("str_to_map(_c1,';','=')")) \
    .selectExpr("*", *[ f"m['{k}'] as `{k}`" for k in keys ]) \
    .show()
+--------------------+--------------------+-----+----+----+-----------------+
|                 _c1|                   m|y2_co|y2_r|y2_z|           y2_org|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----+----+----+-----------------+
|rb=99;cs_y1=0;y2_...|[rb -> 99, cs_y1 ...|   CA|  ON| N2N|Bell DSL Internet|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----+----+----+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks,I get an error .selectExpr("*", *[ f"m['{k}'] as `{k}`" for k in keys ]) \
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: what's your python version? if it's before 3.6, you will need to change f-string to using `"m['{0}'] as {0}".format(k)`.

Comment: or change selectExpr to `.select("*", *[ F.col('m')[k].alias(k) for k in keys ])`

Comment: How do I select only the needed columns i.e. y2_co|y2_r|y2_z|y2_org.Is it possible to do it in the select?

Comment: just remove `"*"` from the select list, for example: `.select([ F.col('m')[k].alias(k) for k in keys ])`.

Comment: @jxc is there way to do this without specifying the array?